# How to add current time to the unlock screen?

Tags: unity, time, lock-screen

I frequently have to unlock my computer just to see what time is it right now. Since time isn't security-sensitive, how can I add it to be displayed on the unlock screen?

This is using Unity, Ubuntu's default shell.

Comment: please edit your question to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

This is a tentative design seen [here](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeOS/Design/Whiteboards/ScreenLock) lots of screenshots

May be available in Gnome 3 watch for the announcement here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/gnomes-new-lock-screen-design-goes-online/

[image]

Comment: I'm using Unity though, not Gnome Shell.

Comment: using mate, I dont see how to install this tentative design.

Answer (score 0):

I can see taking flak for this. I just want to know what time it is. so I opened up tty6 and started this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -vx
#I just want to know the approximate time
while :
do
    banner `date +%H:%M`
    sleep 30
    clear
done
```

now when the lock screen appears, I can just ctrl+alt+F6 and get the time.